# Select record if values exists for same user_id

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-division

I need to get records from a mysql database; in this table there are a list of action associated to users. I need to get all users that have column action = 3 and column action = 5; for example if user nr. 4 has a record with action = 3 and another with action = 5 I get it; if user has only one record with action = 3 or action = 5 I mustn't get it. If I write this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_action 
WHERE action = 3 AND action = 5
```

I always get 0 records. IF i write OR instead of AND I get all records that have action = 3 or action = 5 even if a user doesn't have both value . How ca I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is somewhat called `Relational Division`

```
SELECT  userID
FROM    user_action
WHERE   action IN (3,5)
GROUP   BY userID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT action) = 2
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

if `action` is unique for every `userID`, you can directly `COUNT()` the records without `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  userID
FROM    user_action
WHERE   action IN (3,5)
GROUP   BY userID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

and lastly, if you want to get the whole details of the user, you need to join it with itself,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    user_action a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  userID
            FROM    user_action
            WHERE   action IN (3,5)
            GROUP   BY userID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) b ON a.userID = b.userID
```